# Python3.9 -Encountering 403 Error When Scraping Next.js WebApp with Python's `requests.get()` on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, python-3.9

I'm running into an issue when trying to scrape HTML text from rollercoin.com using Python's `requests.get()` function. Notably, rollercoin.com is built with Next.js.

When running the code locally, I successfully retrieve the HTML content. However, when I deploy the same code to Google App Engine, I get a 403 error.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
python
import requests

url = 'https://rollercoin.com'
redirects = True
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    }
)

html_page = requests.get(url, timeout=20, allow_redirects=redirects, headers=headers)
```

Things I've Tried:

I attempted to scrape HTML content from rollercoin.com using Python's requests.get() function. I initialized custom headers to mimic a web browser, specifically setting the User-Agent and other HTTP headers. My code works as expected when I run it locally; however, I'm encounter issues when deploying it to Google App Engine.
Also, I tried to delete & redeploying the service after making changes.

What I were expecting:
I'm expected the requests.get() function to fetch the HTML content from rollercoin.com successfully, both locally and when deployed on Google App Engine. I anticipated that by mimicking a web browser through custom HTTP headers, I would avoid potential blocking mechanisms that might result in a 403 error.

However, despite My efforts, I receive a 403 error when the code is running on Google App Engine, and I'm looking for a solution to this issue.

Any help or insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446830/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-errors-with-python-requests-even-with-user-agent-head) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75037777/18265702).